# Minimize Application (NOT using trayicon)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have read much about this but I seem to get more confused, the more I read.  I'm using Delphi 2007 and I want to minimize my application at startup, I am not interested in system tray icon, just need a taskbar icon in order to be able to restore the application.

If you take the simplest of all projects with just a main form and in the .dpr file set:

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := true;
Application.ShowMainForm := false;
```

and run the application, there is NO TASKBAR ICON visible thus no way to restore and activate the application.

What is the proper way to minimize on startup without showing the main form then making it minimized?  This would seem so simple but for me it is not.

Comment: Which OS version are you targetting?

Comment: again, I AM NOT WANTING A SYSTEM TRAY ICON.  All I want is a taskbar icon so that the application can be restored/activated by clicking it.  If there is no taskbar icon then how is one to activate the app that was started minimized.  I'm using Delphi 2007, so obviously I am only targeting windows.  And yes, I did say NO TRAY ICON, that was a typo, I meant taskbar icon.  I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed this is simple and explained in the documentation but a bit difficult to find since it is not linked from where you might expect/search for it.

[`System.CmdShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.CmdShow)

> Specifies the flags for displaying the application's main window.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CmdShow := SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE;
  ...
```

It is not documented but the only supported flags are `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE` and `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`, so you can't use `SW_SHOWMINIZED`.

Also, don't forget to remove the `ShowMainForm := false;` statement, otherwise the form won't be visible and hence there won't be any taskbar icon.

**Update**

There's a bug in D2007's `TApplication.Run` (which is corrected at least in XE2) that causes the above solution to prevent the main form to be shown at all. That's a missing `FInitialMainFormState := wsMinimized;` statement in the `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE` case branch.

In D2007 use `WindowState`, but `OnCreate` of the form is too early to set it, the VCL assigns the main form after `OnCreate` runs and modifies some of the window styles. Use `OnShow` together with a flag so that you don't set the window state in the lifetime of the application other than at the startup.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    FRunOneTime: Boolean;
    ..

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not FRunOneTime then begin
    WindowState := wsMinimized;
    FRunOneTime := True;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If Windows is the target OS:

Simply set your main form's `WindowState` property to `wsMinimized` at design time.

You could also do it at runtime in the form's `OnCreate` event:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);
end;
```

Comment: In FormCreate...adding WindowState := wsMinimized; does nothing.  If I add Perform(WM_SYSCOMMAND,sc_minimize,0) then there is a taskbar icon but it is the application window and NOT the main form window, additionally when you click on the task bar icon the main window does appear but it does not have a button.  the main form is designed with a single tbutton on it.  Subsequent clicking the miminize '-' button on the title bar does nothing , it will not minimize.

Comment: My answer does not state to add WindowState := wsMinimized to FormCreate. I'm showing you two ways to minimize your application at startup, which is what you asked.

Comment: I don't want to set it to wsMinimized at design time, I want to eventually determine whether it is to be minimized or not in the dpr and or formcreate and then act accordingly.  I have not been able to figure out how to minimize it at all, so I suppose once that is accomplish I will be able to do it based on the conditionals.